# How to replace string using Regexp_Replace in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to replace this:

```
"STORES/KOL#10/8/36#1718.00#4165570.00#119539388#PT3624496#9902001#04266#6721#PT3624496-11608091-1-55-STORES/KOL"
```

with this:

```
"STORES/KOL#10#8#36#1718.00#4165570.00#119539388#PT3624496#9902001#04266#6721#PT3624496-11608091-1-55-STORES/KOL"
```

basically this is conditional based replace I want to replace `/` with `#`
like `STORES/KOL` string should be `STORES/KOL`
but `10/8/36` string should be `10#8#36`

Comment: Please better explain the logics behind this; for example, do you need to replace the '/' between two digits? the second and third occurrences of '/', … ?

Comment: basically this is conditional based replace I want to replave '/' with '#' like STORES/KOL string should be STORES/KOL but 10/8/36 string should be 10#8#36

Comment: The question is why. Because in '10/8/36' '/' are surrounded by digits? Or any other reason?

Comment: No I want to break this string into columns, actually STORES/KOL should be single column but 10/8/36 will be three different column.

Comment: You have a string with many '/'. How can I know which ones have to be replaced by '#' and which not? What is the logics behind this? Digits? The position in the string? Occurrences?, … ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will replace the 2nd and 3rd `/` character with a `#`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
SELECT '"STORES/KOL#10/8/36#1718.00#4165570.00#119539388#PT3624496#9902001#04266#6721#PT3624496-11608091-1-55-STORES/KOL"'
FROM   DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         value,
         '^(.*?/.*?)/(.*?)/(.*)$',
         '\1#\2#\3'
       ) AS replacement
FROM   test_data
```

**Output**:

```
| REPLACEMENT                                                                                                       |
| :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| "STORES/KOL#10#8#36#1718.00#4165570.00#119539388#PT3624496#9902001#04266#6721#PT3624496-11608091-1-55-STORES/KOL" |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0ec0e3aaa736a46a4282c36d7c3fabdd)*

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using `REGEXP_REPLACE`.  We can try targeting the following regex pattern:

```
#(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)#
```

Then replace using the three capture groups, replacing the path separators with pound signs.

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'STORES/KOL#10/8/36#1718.00#4165570.00#119539388#PT3624496#9902001#04266#6721#PT3624496-11608091-1-55-STORES/KOL' AS input FROM dual
)

SELECT
    input,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(input, '#(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)#', '#\1#\2#\3#') AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Whether or not this regex replacement is specific enough/accurate for the rest of your data depends on that data, which you never showed us.

Answer (score 0):

```
with s as (select '"STORES/KOL#10/8/36#1718.00#4165570.00#119539388#PT3624496#9902001#04266#6721#PT3624496-11608091-1-55-STORES/KOL"' str from dual)
select 
replace(replace(str, '/', '#'), 'STORES#KOL', 'STORES/KOL') result_str_1,
regexp_replace(str, '(\d)/', '\1#')                         result_str_2
from s;
```